# How to migrate from SAP Classic RFC API to Netweaver RFC API

Tags: c, saprfc, netweaver, idoc

Good morning.

We have a working Idoc interface to SAP using the "Classic" API of the SAP RFC SDK. As this is no longer supported we need to migrate to the new Netweaver RFC SDK which comes with a new API. I now have a little trouble in understanding which calls new replace the old ones.

Our interface is built a two C programs, one for SAP inbound (sapclient) and one for SAP outbound (sapserver), both using tRFC.

The sapclient currently uses the following sequence of API functions:

Open Connection

```
RfcConnect
```

Loop:

Fill Internal Data Structure

```
ItCreate("IDOC_CONTROL_REC_40") 
ItCreate("IDOC_DATA_REC_40")
ItAppLine("IDOC_CONTROL_REC_40")
ItAppLine("IDOC_DATA_REC_40")
```

Pass Tables

```
RfcIndirectCall("IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS")
```

Delete Handles

```
ItDelete(firstHandle)
ItDelete(secondHandle)
```

The sapserver program does the following:

Open Connection

```
RfcAccept
```

Set Error Handler

```
RfcEnvironment
```

Transaction Control

```
RfcInstallTransactionControl("RFC_ON_CHECK_TID", "RFC_ON_COMMIT", "RFC_ON_ROLLBACK", "RFC_ON_CONFIRM_TID")
```

Install Function

```
RfcInstallFunction("IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS")
```

Loop: Process Incoming Data

```
RfcDispatch
```

Now, how does that look in the new Netweaver API?

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I recommend these articles from SAP. They describe the NetWeaver API and in each chapter they have a short comparison with the old (classic) API:

Part I -- RFC Client Programming
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/zz27Gg

Part II -- RFC Server Programming
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/9z27Gg

Part III -- Advanced Topics
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/FD67Gg

You will probably need part I for the client communication and part III for the tRFC protocoll (used by IDocs).